# ionic 3 push notification not received on ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to do an android push notification by following this [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) i understood that i need

1. device token
2. api key
3. sender id

i am getting device token and i have created a project in FCM and i got sender id and api key .

but i am not able to receive the push notification form the backend her is my code that i have used in **app.component.ts** file

```
push.hasPermission()
      .then((res: any) => {

        if (res.isEnabled) {
          console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');
        } else {
          console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
        }
      });

      // to initialize push notifications

      const options: PushOptions = {
        android: {
            senderID: '129188921379'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: 'true',
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
      };

      const pushObject: PushObject = push.init(options);

      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
        console.log('Device registered', registration);
        self.deviceToken = registration.registrationId;
      });

      pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
```

> i am not getting any error how do i check where is the mistake from front end or back end
>
> i am not getting any registredId for iphone what is the issue but for android i am getting

Comment: what is `self`?

Comment: i have declared a variable called devicetoken globaly in my .ts file and then to point out to that insted of `this` i am using `self`

Comment: @suraj any idea you got there

Comment: are you able to get any logs printed? put some error callbacks in subscribe

Comment: yes i am able to see my device token console.log in my `chrome://inspect` @suraj

Comment: @suraj please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You are calling .hasPermission before push.init